# Logging when /tmp full

Tags: disk-space

I'm trying to track a bug which corrupted some tables in mysql and I need to know, what happens if /tmp gets full at the same time some `update` query executes, will it fail? If does, where does this get logged? If doesn't is there a way to log that?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question was very difficult to decipher so I edited to make it more legible, is that still asking the same question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to know what happens to an application attempting to write to a file if the disk is full.

The answer is that the [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) call will return `ENOSPC`.

How a particular application responds to that error will vary, but for mysql it appears it will throw an error similar to the following: `Error writing file '/var/log/mysql.log' (Errcode :28)`

Where `perror 28` shows : `OS error code  28:  No space left on device`